# How to get raw video file from Google drive link to append in website

Tags: javascript

I have a video uploaded on Google drive. The link below is supposed to give a raw file. (Video file)

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxx
```

When I visit the link I get
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBTRn.jpg)

How to get the real playable link so that I can use video tag to play on my site

```
<video src="__link__" controls width=560 height=315></video>
```

Edit: to make it simple, I can use Java in my web app. Maybe we could fetch the page which says download anyway and get the information from the form and parse it into a link and return it. The form contains information like

[Form code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENbAt.jpg)

This is one time code and it generates new one automatically. But, [https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?export=download&id=[XXX]&uuid=[XXX]&authuser=0&confirm=t&at=[XXX]](https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?export=download&id=%5BXXX%5D&uuid=%5BXXX%5D&authuser=0&confirm=t&at=%5BXXX%5D)

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use Google Drive to host your video file for your site in the first place?

Comment: I really want to use Google drive as a storage for my web assets. It should be some how possible. Images are working just fine.

Comment: To generate playable link. You can build link like this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/VIDEO_ID/preview                                                                But i don't think it will play on video tag. Use iframe instead

Answer (score 1):

By web assets, I'm not sure if you mean assets for one website or all assets for all your websites, but regardless you don't want to use Google Drive to host your assets. If you have a lot of images and video and are worried about performance, then you should use a CDN. Cloudinary is a great choice, and you can sign up for free. Google Drive isn't a choice to be considered because it's not a CDN.

https://cloudinary.com/